# How can I set a custom width on my Google search iframe?

Tags: google-search, google-custom-search

I am trying to use google search for my site:

http://www.houseofhawkins.com/search.php

It is not playing nice with some screen resolutions.  Here is the code given from google:

```
<div id="cse-search-results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var googleSearchIframeName = "cse-search-results";
  var googleSearchFormName = "cse-search-box";
  var googleSearchFrameWidth = 250;
  var googleSearchDomain = "www.google.com";
  var googleSearchPath = "/cse";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

I changed the "googleSearchFrameWidth" down to 250 thinking that should be setting the width in px, (it was 600 to start with).  But with smaller screens (1024 * 768) it sticks out the side of my divs.

Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: P.S... what should I be wrapping my code segments in please?  Obviously not [code] :p

Comment: You can just indent each line of code by 4 spaces.

Comment: Just click the code button in the toolbar. Already fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same trouble you did wanting to resize the iFrame. You'd think changing the `googleSearchFrameWidth` value would do the trick, but nope.

So I resorted to DOM manipulation. Since the name of the iFrame is "`googleSearchFrame`", Right after the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js"></script>
```

reference, I added another `<script>` tag with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByName('googleSearchFrame').item(0).width = 600;
</script>
```

The above sets the width of the iFrame at `600px`. In your case, obviously, you'd want to set it to `250`. If you're paranoid that Google might change the iFrame name some day, just go with the `getElementsByTagName('iFrame')` method and narrow it down to the position of your iFrame in the document (if you have multiple iFrames).

Answer (score 6):

I have three settings that you can tweak, a combination of which I hope will get you where you need to go:

1. **googleSearchFrameWidth** - Set this in the JavaScript to your desired width. This is the most obvious one and the one you've probably already tweaked.
2. **Width of cse-search-results div** - Use an inline style statement (e.g. `style ="width:500"`) to set the width of the div.
3. **Set the IFrame Style** - If you check, you'll probably notice that all of this content is being rendered from Google via an IFrame. This is a bit harder to tweak but doable. To do this, add a statement to the end of your stylesheet such as `#cse-search-results iframe { }`, including the actual iframe style within the brackets.

I hope one of these or a combination of these proves to be the answer for you. When in doubt, use a DOM inspector such as the one available in Firebug to analyze the impact of your changes on the DOM. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is anyone running into an issue where their search results line is getting cut off? #3 works great, but it's cutting my typography lines...very strange, can't figure out.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 22/06/10** - Found a simpler solution that below. Change the **FORID** value in the in code to **FORID:11**. Therefore one line of you code should look similar to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:11;NB:1" />
```

---

Try just adding

```
#cse-search-results iframe {width: 100%;}
```

in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Easy steps to modify the **googleSearchFrameWidth** in your site:

1. DOWNLOAD your own 'show_afs_search.js' file from http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js and save it in the same directory where you have you results.htm webpage.
2. Open your results.htm webpage and MODIFY the line code into the script
   ... src="http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js" TO: src="show_afs_search.js"
3. Open your own 'show_afs_search.js' file and MODIFY the setting width:a
   to width:"600" 
   (or whatever you want to set the width in pixels) and save your own 'show_afs_search.js' file.
4. Upload both files to your hosting site at the same directory: results.htm and show_afs_search.js'

DONE!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("iframe[name='googleSearchFrame']").css("width","100%");
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google will not allow you to use a width smaller than 500px. Your best bet is to create a style for the iframe:

```
<style>
#cse-search-results iframe {width: 200px; }
</style>
```