# Validation error in allowtransparency attribute on the iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, transparency

I am using facebook like for my website. So i used `allowTransparency='true'` but in the case of validation its showing error like this:

> The allowtransparency attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use
>   CSS instead.

How to fix this problem ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have apparently used a so-called HTML5 validator. When it reports something as “obsolete”, it means that the construct works, but the HTML5 drafts tell authors not to use it. So this is a problem only if you take it as a problem, or someone (like company rules that require “valid markup”) make it a problem.

Cf. to the question [There is no attribute “allowtransparency”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740700/there-is-no-attribute-allowtransparency). Some answers to it comment on some alternate ways.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer.

Comment: well.. thats not entirely correct.. HTML5 validation gives a warning, but you can still use the *case-sensitive* attribute for other browsers (or if you use a doctype that is older then `<!DOCTYPE html>`...)

 just add to the IFRAME's attribute list:

`<!--[if IE] allowTransparency="true" -->`

hope it helps..

Comment: @EladKarako, which part of the answer is not correct? You are suggesting the use of old doctypes or an IE “pseudocomment” trick to prevent an error message from an HTML5 validator. But how does this refute anything in the answer? (And it is an error message, not a warning.)