# Meta tag 'there is no attribute "property" ' and other attribute error:

Tags: html, xhtml, meta-tags, meta

I tried to validate my site and i get this following error

**there is no attribute "property"**

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Free Sms" />
```

**there is no attribute "allowTransparency"**

```
…w:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">Facebook</iframe>
```

**there is no attribute "placeholder"**

```
…"search" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH" value="" class="searchInp …
```

First my code has this and i get 13 errors.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Changing the code to this reduce my error. but I get the 3 errors.Why? Any guide how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Complete

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>Welcome to mysite</title>
                   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                   <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> 
                   <meta name="keywords" content="Social, Programming" />
                   <meta name="description" content="Share Ideas and become the best" />
                   <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
                   <meta name="robots" content="*" />
                   <meta name="document-type" content="text" />
                   <meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP" />
                   <meta name="slurp" content="NOYDIR" />
                   <meta name="msnbot" content="NOODP" />
                   <meta name="Generator" content="snippet" />
                   <meta property="og:title" content="Welcome to mysite" />
                   <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
                   <meta property="og:url" content="" />
                   <meta property="og:description" content="Share Ideas and become the best" />
                   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="" />
                   <meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/images/fbicon.png" />
```

Comment: Just use `<!DOCTYPE html>` for HTML5

Comment: my site is still not in html5 :(

Comment: `placeholder` is an HTML5 attribute, so you'll always get errors under xHTML Transitional. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740700/there-is-no-attribute-allowtransparency) is info regarding the `allowTransparency` attribute.

Comment: i see.. so im force to  use html5. thanks for the link on allowTransparency

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The attributes you mention are simply not part of XHTML 1.0 Transitional, so a validator has to report them as errors. Just remember that the concept of error is relative here: it means that the document does not conform to the document type definition it purports to comply with (by referring to a document type definition by the `doctype` declaration).

The `property` attribute is not part of HTML5 CR either, but validators like http://validator.nu use a  “schema for HTML5 + SVG 1.1 + MathML 3.0 + RDFa Lite 1.1”, where the RDFa part allows `property`.

If your markup is a mix of XHTML 1.0 Transitional and HTML5, for example, just relax. The mix works in browsers and other relevant software, except for validators, which need to be picky. Just use a `doctype` that best corresponds to the markup you have, and manually check the error messages. If you get just 3 error messages when using XHTML 1.0 Transitional, keep using it, until you get fewer errors when checking against HTML5.

Comment: when i use doctype html5 i got lot of errors most of it are obsolete property.is it ok also to mixed it up? what happens to the tags or property that are obsolete in html5?

Comment: @Snippet, nothing happens to tags or attributes that are declared “obsolete” in HTML5. It’s just words, and HTML5 *requires* browsers to continue supporting “obsolete” features, and in any case they do so.

Comment: i see.thanks. How about my meta tags. when i change doctype to html5 some of my meta tags gat error like  Bad value msnbot for attribute name on element meta: Keyword msnbot is not registered

Comment: @Snippet, similarly, it’s just about HTML5 requirements on documents (authors); they do not affect browsers or robots. The `meta` tags have their effects (usually none – most `meta` tags are really write-only) quite independently of HTML5 restrictions on the `name` and `http-equiv` attributes.

Comment: Thanks for everything.i haven't change it to html five because of too many errors, using same doctype i have fixed the property error by changing to 'name' only the placeholder is now my problem