# how do i make iframe not transparent and work over text?

Tags: html, css, iframe

this is my iframe code in my html page:
  `<iframe src="menu.htm" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="500" height="500"></iframe>`

the iframe is for a multiple level menu and i need it to be on a lot of pages and i just want to update the iframe and not need to update all of the webpages.
i'm having a few problems:
the iframe is transparent. how do i fix that?
once the menu goes over the text, it doesn't work. how do i make it work?

i tried looking for other things all over the internet, but i couldn't find anything. please help!!!

Comment: try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740700/there-is-no-attribute-allowtransparency