# Transparent Iframe Background

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, iframe

I am trying to create an app which displays a form made on Google Apps Script with a transparent background. After looking through several StackOverflow posts, I have found that setting the `background-color` CSS element of the body tag and adding `allowtransparency="true"` to the Iframe will do the trick. However, my Iframe still displays a white background. As far as I could tell, there were no errors either on the Google Apps Script side or my Iframe side. Thank you!

**Edit:** I have found that Google Apps Script embeds your web app into an Iframe which could affect how the `background-color` tag works since there is now 2 `body` tags where the highest one has `background-color: white`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is no attribute "allowtransparency"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740700/there-is-no-attribute-allowtransparency)

Comment: In short, if you want transparency, do not set a background-color.

Comment: Isn't changing the background-color to transparent helping in this case?

Comment: The linked answer says: *The source page cannot set its own background. If it does, it ignores the transparent background.*

Comment: I have just edited my question with a new finding. Do you know of anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where and how you are using the app instead of relying on Google to generate the iframe you could create the iframe yourself. I have had some luck with this by creating a simple html page, hosting that through GitHub pages. That html page would essentially only consist of an iframe, which can have whatever attributes you would like. You may be able to host the html file out of Google Drive if you want to stay within the Google ecosystem.